# Regular Expression to deny input of repeated characters in for Email Validation

Tags: c#, regex

I tried the following regular expression to deny the user from entering email ID such as **joooohn.smiiiithhh@xxxdddd.xxx**

```
    @"^((?!\1{2,})([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))(?!\1{2,})@((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])(?!\1{2,})\.
([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])(?!\1{2,})\.
([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])(?!\1{2,})\.
(?!\1{2,})([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)
(?!\1{2,})+(?!\1{2,})[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$"
```

But It didn't work. Can anyone help

**Edit:
  1. Not more than twice can a character appear.**

Comment: will you please elaborate your question, means after how many repetitions it will give error and all.

Comment: /me wonders why such e-mails should be prohibited...

Comment: what if I have e-mail registered in `.xxx` domain?

Comment: what if my email address domain name is `google.com`?

Comment: Two **oo** not a problem, .xxx can be a domain but I am asked to check that too.. requirements!

Comment: Why exactly would you ever want to do this?

Comment: Why bother? breee@zaaark.com might well be a perfectly valid email address. You will block potentially legitimate emails addresses.

Comment: **1.** Email validation is a bad idea. **2.** Email validation [using a regex is a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/7586). **3.** Limiting repeated characters is a bad idea, because those are valid emails. **4.** [Just check for `@` and `.`](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/78354/3677). Really. **5.** If people don't want to give you an email, you will not get their email.

Comment: If a double o isn't a problem, then you need to be more specific about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Send email with validation link to given address. If validation link was called, email address is valid. No need for regex.

Comment: I updated the question with this point

Comment: @Kobi I agree with your point(s) thanks for being elaborate

Comment: There is nothing more frustrating than some system telling you that your email address isn't valid when you've been using it just fine for years

Comment: For the record: [Here is my answer from 2009](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1000825/7586) for email validation in .Net - I'd do the same today. If the email is supported by my mail client, I'm good with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(\w)\1\1` should do the trick.

The `\w` matches any word character and puts it in the first capture group, then `\1` checks for that same capture group, so this will match any string with three instances of a word character in a row. So any email which does **NOT** match this regex would be valid by your criteria.

As others have said, doing this validation is probably a bad idea, but if this is a requirement you've been given and can't avoid, the above solution will work. Alternatively you could use this to present the user with a warning, rather than reject the email altogether.

Comment: Related: http://www.iiiiiiii.com/ (this isn't a counter example, just some music)

Comment: @Kobi matches the pattern, as it should. Hopefully it's relatively clear from the last paragraph of my answer that this isn't an endorsement of blocking emails based on this pattern. But sometimes developers are given requirements that they have to implement whether or not they agree with them. And I could perhaps see value in it just placing an unobtrusive "Warning: this email contains repeated characters, please check that it is correct" next to the entry field- though it's not something I'd choose to do myself.

Comment: "(this isn't a counter example, just some music)" Ah :)

Answer (score 0):

Bellow should work

^((.)\2{0,1}(?!\2))*$

Comment: Not working for me. e.g. blaaah@google.com and blaah@google.com, neither of which match