# Email validation issue

Tags: vb.net, validation

I am trying to validate email address field. I did it using `Regex` and it works fine but the issue is

I have set `e.cancel` to `True` in `validating` event, due to which it doesn't allow user to change focus unless user enters a correct email-id, even this is not the problem but it wont even allow the user to close the window/form.

I mean if the user is trying to `abort` the `complete transaction` what is the need of him/her to enter valid email id.

Here is my code -

```
  Private Sub tbemail_Validating(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles tbemail.Validating

    Dim pattern As String = "^[a-z][a-z|0-9|]*([_][a-z|0-9]+)*([.][a-z|0-9]+([_][a-z|0-9]+)*)?@[a-z][a-z|0-9|]*\.([a-z][a-z|0-9]*(\.[a-z][a-z|0-9]*)?)$"


    Dim match As System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match = Regex.Match(tbemail.Text.Trim(), pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    If (match.Success) Then
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid email id", "Checking")
        e.Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't ever write silly `If...Else` statements like that. If you have an empty `If` block then you just wrote bad code. If you only care about one condition then test for that and drop the `Else`, i.e. `If Not match.Success Then`.

Comment: Yup! I will keep that in mind. Thanks

Comment: There's a better way to check for a valid email address: [Validating an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14075010/1115360). Basically, `Try` to make a `New MailAddress(tbemail.Text.Trim())`.

Comment: [ErrorProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.errorprovider) Class

Comment: @jmcilhinney one exception would be if you want to "document" in the code that you did consider the alternate condition of the `If` in design, but you want nothing to happen. However, there should be at lease a COMMENT in that branch. e.g. `If x = 1 Then ' Business owner explicitly wants nothing to happen when it's 1 Else DoSomething End If`

Comment: @jmcilhinney I found the source of my comment above. Code Complete 2nd Edition, page 358: `One option is to code the else clause—with a null statement if necessary—to show that the else case has been considered. Coding null elses just to show that that case has been considered might be overkill, but at the very least, take the else case into account. When you have an if test without an else, unless the reason is obvious, use comments to explain why the else clause isn’t necessary...`

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `CausesValidation` property of your *Cancel* button to `False`. That way, clicking it will not cause the `Validating` event to be raised and you can close the form even if the data in the last control is invalid.  This assumes that the form was displayed by calling `ShowDialog`.

Comment: if I set the CausesValidation property of the Cancel button to False, user will be able to enter wrong values in the field. I just don't want to let the user enter wrong value.

Comment: You specifically said that the issue was that you couldn't close the form if the user entered invalid data. I told you how to be able to close the form if the user entered invalid data.

Comment: In that sense removing the validating event was the better option. Even that would allow me to close the form.

Comment: *"I mentioned that proactively in my question"*. No you didn't. There's no mention of `CausesValidation` in your question. Are you confusing `CausesValidation` and `e.Cancel`?. You're just taking something so simple and making it complicated. The user can enter invalid data whenever they want. There's nothing you can do to stop that. What you can do is prevent them progressing with that invalid data. If they click the *Cancel* button then they're not progressing. If they are cancelling, it doesn't make any different what's in any control because you're not going to use any of the data.